# Insulating shower stud corner

Tags: insulation

I have a corner in a shower location that butts up against one exterior wall of the house, and as you can see there it is enclosed yet there is no insulation in there. What is the best way to insulate this corner? I have yet to find a good consensus on the internet. Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would drill a 1/2 hole in one of those studs, every 12 inches, and put closed cell spray foam in that cavity. Closed cell is mold/mildew resistant and will expand at a reasonable rate to fill that area.

Comment: Suggest you use 'low expand' foam ('doors and windows'), rather than regular. Practice at the bottom to understand how much is the right amount before you do the top. When you pause between bottom and top, leave a large blob of foam coming out of the tube so that the tube itself won't clog.